# Why am I getting a seg fault when inserting into a map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to insert the contents of one map to another. Here is the code:

```
std::map<std::string, int> Student::getGrades() const;
...

for(set<Student*, Cmp>::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); ++it)
{
    grades.clear();
    grades.insert((*it)->getGrades().begin(), (*it)->getGrades().end());
    for(map<string, int>::const_iterator itt = grades.begin(); itt!=grades.end(); ++itt)
    {
       if(itt->first == course && itt->second >= score1 && itt->second <= score2)
            (*it)->display(cout);
    }
}
```

s is a set that contains pointers to student objects and each student objects has a getGrades() method that returns a map. I'm trying to find grades that match grades that I have read in from a file and print the record corresponding to those grades. However, the insert method is giving me a seg fault. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Student::getGrades()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case `getGrades()` returns a copy of the grade map and not a reference, `begin()` and `end()` would belong to 2 different maps.

You should probably make a local copy, and simplify the code like this:

```
for(set<Student*, Cmp>::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it!=s.end(); ++it)
{
    map<string, int> grades = (*it)->getGrades();
    for(map<string, int>::const_iterator itt = grades.begin(); itt!=grades.end(); ++itt)
    {
        if(itt->first == course && itt->second >= score1 && itt->second <= score2)
            (*it)->display(cout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be an uninitialized pointer in the set `s`.